# Unable to dismiss the suggested duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, post-notices

Today someone suggested that my post was a duplicate of another post. I disagreed and dismissed the message by selecting the [No] button below, and clicking the [Submit] button.

This however doesn't dismiss this question. It comes back time and time again when reloading the post.

[image]